# Enforcing a regex to be wrapped with quotation marks from both sides or not at all without duplicating the expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I have an expression that should either be wrapped with quotation marks from both sides or not at all, and I want to create a regex to capture this expression.
The point is, I don't want to duplicate the expression.
For example, if the expression is any single letter in english then the duplicated regex would be

```
^[a-z]|'[a-z]'$
```

Now both `a` and `'a'` would be accepted.

Is there a way to define this regex without duplicating the expression?

Comment: I just noticed, you didn't specify a regex flavour. From your previous activity on the site, is it python?

Comment: not specific, if it's good [here](https://regexr.com/) it's good for me

Comment: Added the PCRE tag for you, since regexr supports it. You _need_ to specify a regex flavour for a [tag:regex] question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
^('?)[a-z]\1$
```

In group 1, match `'` or nothing. And after the `[a-z]` part, match what we matched in group 1 (`\1`). So either:

- group 1 matches `'`, in which case `\1` matches `'` --> `^'[a-z]'$`, or;
- group 1 matches nothing, in which case `\1` matches nothing --> `^[a-z]$`

Therefore, this matches the same things as `^([a-z]|'[a-z]')$.`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iju21y/1)

Comment: Nice, but I wonder if there's a way to achieve it without creating an additional backreference.

Comment: @HaoWu Seems like Enrico has found such a way :) It doesn't have back references, but uses a lookahead...

Comment: @Sweeper, I frankly think your solution is the way to go, ahahah. Mine is long and ugly.

Answer (score 1):

What about [this](https://regex101.com/r/6eYiV4/1)?

```
^(?:'|(?=.*[^']$))[a-z]'?$
```

Actually this is broken, as it also matches `'a`. [This](https://regex101.com/r/6eYiV4/3) is better, but a bit longer too:

```
^(?:'(?=.*')|(?=[^']+$))[a-z]'?$
```

Explanation of this second, working version:

- `[a-z]'?$` matches the letter optionally followed by a `'` at the end of the line. Whether this single quote is there or not is governed by the other part of the regex
- `^(?:'(?=.*')|(?=[^']+$))` matches a `'` if the line also ends with `'`, or just a bunch of non-single quotes (well, in reality just one)

  - `(?:…)` is a non-capturing group
  - `'(?=.*')` is the alternative that matches *and consumes* the leading `'` if the line end with a `'` too; the reason why `(?=.*')` and not `(?=.*'$)` is just that the `$` is already imposed by the other piece of the regex
  - `(?=[^']+$)` doesn't consume anything, but only asserts that the line does not have single quotes

Comment: can you please add explanation to what is done here? it does work but I need to understand it

Answer (score 1):

Another option could asserting that the string does not consists of a single `'` using a single negative lookahead.

```
^(?![^'\r\n]*'[^'\r\n]*$)'?[a-z]'?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what from this position at the right is not

  - `[^'\r\n]*'[^'\r\n]*$` Match a single occurrence of `'` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `)` Close lookahead
- `'?[a-z]'?` Match `[a-z]` between optional `'`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/obdfi5/1)

Comment: This is just Sweeper's answer with a different regex flavour.

Comment: @Enrico Is is not a different regex flavour, it is an alternative in case the `[a-z]` is a pattern instead of a fixed value.

Comment: Wasn't it the same before you changed it?

Comment: @Enrico No it was different, see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64588344/revisions But then I realized that is would also match `'a` because it recurses the subpattern, and that matches an optional `'`